# Unable to Understand how auto wiring is done in the below class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

below is the class which has constructor args which gets autoWired, but what i don't understand is that how the constructor gets autowired here without specifying any annotation or without mentioning it in any xml file.
I am kind of baffled with the code.

```
@Loggable
@Slf4j
public class DefaultDirectPlusService extends AbstractDnBDirectPlusService implements DirectPlusService {

public DefaultDnBDirectPlusService(String baseURL, RestTemplate restTemplate, DnBMetricsRepository dnbMetricsRepository, Environment env) {
  super(restTemplate, dnbMetricsRepository, env);
  this.baseURL = baseURL;
}
```

Here the question is how does baseURL gets populated without any annotations or the xml configuration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As specified in the documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation), starting with Spring 4.3, if a class has only one constructor, Spring will automatically use that constructor for autowiring.
If you would have more than one constructor (you can try it out), you need to add the `@Autowired` annotation to the constructor which you want Spring to use.

Comment: Got it:) Thanks dunni